# What is this crazy German character combination to represent an umlaut?

Tags: text, encoding, diacritics

I was just parsing the following [website](https://www.bild.de/politik/inland/politik-inland/nach-merkel-rueckzug-kann-man-kanzler-werden-wenn-58140544.bild.html).

There one finds the text

```
und wären damit auch
```

At first, the "ä" looks perfectly fine, but once I inspect it, it turns out that this is not the regular "ä" (represented as ascw 228) but this:

```
ascw: 97, char: a
ascw: 776, char: ¨
```

I have never before seen an "ä" represented like this.

How can it happen that a website uses this weird character combination and what might be the benefit from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you don't mention in your questions is the used encoding. Quite obviously it is a Unicode based encoding.

In Unicode, code point U+0308 (776 in decimal) is the [combining diaeresis](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm). Out of the letter `a` and the diaeresis, the German character `ä` is created.

There are indeed two ways to represent German characters with umlauts (ä in this case). Either as a single code point:

```
U+00E4 latin small letter A with diaeresis
```

Or as a sequence of two code points:

```
U+0061 latin small letter A
U+0308 combining diaeresis
```

Similarly you would combine two code points for an upper case 'Ä':

```
U+0041 latin capital letter A
U+0308 combining diaeresis
```

In most cases, Unicode works with two codes points as it requires fewer code points to enable a wide range characters with diacritics. However for historical reasons a special code point exist for letters with German umlauts and French accents.

The Unicode libraries is most programming languages provide functions to *normalize* a string, i.e. to either convert all sequences into a single code point if possible or extend all single code points into the two code point sequence. Also see [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Comment: So Capital letter "A" followed by U+0308 would be "Ä", right?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, this was the answer or original problem with the name of a fileupload.

```
Cannot convert argument 2 to ByteString because the character at index 6 has value 776 which is greater than 255
```

For future references.

Answer (score -1):

The use of the word "diaeresis" to describe the correctly characterised "umlaut" is wrong. A diaeresis is found on the second of two vowels placed together to indicate that they should be pronounced separately. An umlaut is placed over a single letter to indicate that it is pronounced differently (in German "um" = change and "laut" = sound) as though it were combined with an "e".